# Python HtmlParser changing the html file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on an old website that needs to have their strings internationalized. So I used html parser for reading all html files recursively to find all strings that are eligible for changing and added them to a dictionary with string as a key and a counter as value to get each unique string to a unique identifier. Now I got all keys and all values from the project and I want to replace the original strings with their unique identifiers. But some of the strings match other parts of the project unintended. So I wonder if it is possible to modify values while working on them.

My aim is to parse this file:

```
<html>
    ...
    <p> something $$$ otherthing </p>
    <img title="foo bar $$$ something" />
    <h1> something something </h1>
```

And change it to:

```
<html>
    ...
    <p> string_1 $$$ string_2 </p>
    <img title="string_3 $$$ string_1" />
    <h1> string_1 string_1 </h1>
```

Here is my code for better explanation:

```
import glob
import re
from html.parser import HTMLParser

wordDic = {}
counter = 1

class MyParse(HTMLParser):
    def handle_data(self, data):
        global wordDic
        global counter
        if self.currentTag == 'script' or self.currentTag == 'style':
            return
        if len(val) == 0 or val == '$$$': # $$$ is a custom name that I want to keep
            return
        wordDic[val] = counter
        counter = counter + 1
        # Now is there a way for me to modify the html file after this in this method?
```

Thanks in advance.